# unable to install any software using sudo command

Tags: sudo, dpkg

I am unable to install any software using `sudo` command;

```
rahul@rahul-VPCEA33EN:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands on terminal to install vlc,

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
 sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
 sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I'd check WHAT is using the files right now before radically removing lock files.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have another process locking that resource, another instance of apt-get in a different terminal or even the graphical software center, synaptics, ubuntu-software-center ...